# Taking the dotproduct a 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, dot-product

I want to take the dotproduct for a sigmoid function.

```
import numpy as np


def sigmoid(x):
    sigm = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
    return sigm


def p(D, w, b):
    prob=sigmoid(np.dot(D[:,7],w)+b)
    return prob
```

Works

```
    x = np.array([D[0,7], D[0,9]])
    w = np.array([w1, w2])
    prob=sigmoid(np.dot(x[:],w)+b)
```

also works, however

```
    x = np.array([D[:,7], D[:,9]])
    w = np.array([w1, w2])
    prob=sigmoid(np.dot(x,w)+b)
```

does NOT work.
It throws a dimensional alignment error.

```
ValueError: shapes (2,426) and (2,) not aligned: 426 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

I guess I could use a loop to iterate the first array position, but maybe Python3 has a way to do this more elegantly.
How can I format the array correctly so it gets accepted as input for the numpy.dot() function ?

Comment: What are the shapes of x,w,and b? What are those of D, w1, and w2?

Comment: b = int; D = 2D array of x*13; w1 = int; w2 = int

Comment: `[:]` does nothing.

Comment: You are correct; I have edited it out of the post. Had no impact on problem.

Comment: I mean what are the number of columns and the number of rows? For example, if `a=np.array([[5,6,7],[-1,9,2]])`, then `a` has the shape of `(2,3)`, i.e., 2 rows and 3 columns. You can get the shape by `a.shape`.

Comment: For `A.dot(B)` the last dimension of `A` has to match the 2nd to the last of `B`.  That's consistent with the usual 'scan across rows, and down columns' when taking a matrix product.  With `matmul/@` is it possible to take 'batches` of dot products, where batches are the initial dimensions of 3d (and higher) arrays.  There's also an `einsum` that's even more flexible with regards to dot products.

Comment: Shape of D is (426, 14)

Comment: Then, `x.shape` is `(2,426)`. Assuming `w1` and `w2` are just scalers, `w.shape` is `(2,)`. Then, isn't the correct order `np.dot(w,x)`, instead of `np.dot(x,w)`? I'm not sure about the underlying mathematical formulation, but maybe it'd be worth checking the correct order.

Comment: @hpaulj I think that I am essentially missing a Dimension for x.

Comment: The error indicates that `x` has (2, 426) shape, and `w` (2,).  `x.T` would pair those correctly, so would `np.dot(w, x)`, resulting in a (426,) array.

Comment: @norio The dotproduct is commutative; ie np.dot(a,b)==np.dot(b,a). Also note that the intention is not align the shapes by using the correct amount of dimensions for x.

Comment: @hpaulj You are correct. You fixed it. Apparently I misunderstood the Wikipedia entry about dotproducts, as it mentiones commutative properties.

Comment: @norio You were right. Apparently np.dot(a,b)!=np.dot(b,a), or at least not here. Switching the input fixed it.

Comment: Can someone explain why the other two example methods worked despite being ordered the other way around ?

Comment: In the second example, `x.shape` is `(2,)`. It is not any more a matrix but a vector. In the first example, you need to review the shape of `D` that you passed to the function `p`. Maybe it happened to be `(2,something)`.

Comment: I just read the Wikipedia article again, but to me it seems like a and b should always be interchangeable. Wolframalpha also says that. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DotProduct.html D was always the same array.

Comment: If `x` and `y` are both vectors of real-valued elements, then `x dot y = y dot x`. However, in your case, one of them is a matrix and the other is a vector. You can still use `np.dot` to do such a matrix-vector multiplication, but now you need to be careful about the order -- one order is valid, but the operation is not defined for the other order -- unless the matrix is square. Please take a look at matrix-matrix multiplication, and reduce it to matrix-vector multiplication, and then to vector-vector multiplication. The last one is the dot product you looked up in wikipedia and wolfram.